# Lazy Loading with Function Imports

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, lazy-loading

I have a function import that is returning me a dataset of type `Package` which has a property called `PackageRoles` with is a foreign key reference to a list of `PackageRole` objects.

When I call my function import like this...

```
List<Package> orders = db.GetTopOrders();
```

I get my list but `PackageRoles` property has not been populated.

Is there a way of getting this to populate using an `Include()` for example?  I need to be able to get these without wanting to iterate over the `Packages` ideally.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a way of doing it so I have settled for this approach.  Enumerate the result into a List<> and then iterate over the list, loading in the properties that you want using the LoadProperty on your ObjectContext.

```
List<Package> orders = db.GetTopOrders().ToList();

foreach (var order in orders)
{
    db.LoadProperty<Package>(order, o => o.PackageRoles);
}
```